# Odd problem regarding 'apt-get update'

Tags: debian, apt

I was having some serious network troubles, and now running `sudo apt-get update` gives this error:

```
...
Hit ftp://ftp.is.co.za experimental/contrib i386 Packages
Reading package lists... Error!
E: Encountered a section with no Package: header
E: Problem with MergeList /var/lib/apt/lists/ftp.is.co.za_debian_dists_testing_main_binary-i386_Packages
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
```

It's an odd one because I've never seen it before. Have you experienced it? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Steps to fix:

1. Disable Testing suite
2. `sudo apt-get update`
3. Re-enable Testing suite
4. `sudo apt-get update`

Answer (score 4):

The file was corrupted somewhere. I thought running `apt-get update` would fix it. If it doesn't, remove the file (`sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/ftp.is.co.za_debian_dists_testing_main_binary-i386_Packages`) and try `apt-get update`. If that still downloads a broken file, there may be an invalid entry in a cache somewhere between you and the server. Try using a different Debian mirror for a couple of days.

Comment: I strongly suspect that your approach would work. I've Accepted mine though because it's what I used (which was just before I saw your Answer).